# changing the images according to the definition (array)

Tags: image, actionscript-3, dictionary

I'm making a small and funny dictionary.

So far, I've got a search bar. When the user enters a word he's got the definition. 
I'm wondering if it's possible to associate an image to a definiton.

Here's my code :

```
public class Main extends Sprite{

        private var ac:AutoComplete;
        private var conteneurImage:Loader = new Loader();
        private var image:URLRequest = new URLRequest("images/tannoy.gif");
        conteneurImage.load(image);
        private var fruitArray:Array = [
        {label:"A bloc", Type:"Très fort", Description:"une boîte de achards"}, 
        {label:"A fond", Type:"vie", Description:"Loulou"}, 
        {label:"dfgdf", Type:"à grande vitesse.", Description:"Indique une vitesse"}, 
        private var bg:Sprite;
        // A couple of TextFields
        private var t1:TextField;
        private var t2:TextField;
        // An input TextField to show our search results
        private var it1:TextField;
        // A couple of TextFormats
        private var titleFormat:TextFormat;
        private var titleFormatW:TextFormat;
        // Two variables to hold our x and y positions
        private var xPos:int;
        private var yPos:int;


// Whenever we need to see the List component which is part of the AutoComplete class, an event is dispatched by the AutoComplete class and is picked up in the ListDepth function
        // This takes our instance of the AutoComplete class - ac - and moves it to the highest available depth, which is the numChildren ( all the elements on stage ) - 1.
        private function listDepth(e:Event):void{
            setChildIndex(ac, numChildren - 1);
        }

        // This function is also a response to an event dispatched from the AutoComplete class. It takes the results, or lack of them, and displays that information in our it1 TextField
        private function setDisplay(e:Event):void{
            var fIndex:int = ac.aIndex;
            if(fIndex == -1){
                it1.text = ac.noResult;
                it1.setTextFormat(titleFormat);
            }else{
                it1.htmlText = "<b>Définition rapide :</b> " + fruitArray[fIndex].Type + "<br/><br/><b>Définition complète:</b> " + fruitArray[fIndex].Description;
                it1.setTextFormat(titleFormat);
            }
        }
```

So, do you think it's possible to associate an image with a label ?

Something like

```
 <img src="smiley.gif">
```

or in

```
it1.htmlText = "<b>Définition rapide :</b> " + fruitArray[fIndex].Type + "<br/><br/><b>Définition complète:</b> " + fruitArray[fIndex].Description;
```

maybe add a code that tells to go search an image in this line.

How do you think I can do that ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend two choices:

1) Make a class Word (or any other name that would make sense). In this class make a variable for the word itself or an array of names if you want. Also add a variable for the image and any other data you'd like to keep.

Here's an example:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;


    public class Word
    {

        public var en_name:String;
        public var fr_name:String;

        public var image:DisplayObject;
        public var imageURL:String;

        private var imageLoader:Loader;

        public function loadImage():void
        {
            imageLoader = new Loader();
            imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
            imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(imageURL));
        }

        private function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
            image = imageLoader.content;
            imageLoader = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Now instead of your string arrays make arrays of Words. You'll be able to access their names in different languages and image. I've even included a loader if you want to load the image from outside (or you can assign the image var directly). This is not the most scalable version for a dictionary, but you have the freedom to extend and improve it as you see fit.

2) Slightly less elegant, - just make arrays of strings and images. And when you access the array of name, like fruitArray[4], you can also access the image array with the same access point, like fruitPictureArray[4]

Hope that helps!